# How can I print a map into widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was trying to print a map into a widget, but no result. Also, I would like to print a loop two Widgets `SocialMediaBubbles` and `SizedBox` but with the condition to don't print the last with a `Sizedbox` widget.

Variable

```
final Map<String, String> socialMedia = {
  kWeb: 'http://candice-music.com',
  kYouTube: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WW7K3WWin_8',
  kInstagram: 'https://www.instagram.com/candicemusicoff/',
  kSpotify: 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1rHf7vRCsDRBkbA1XGT9e1'
};
```

And what I was trying

```
socialMedia.isNotEmpty
  ? Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
          socialMedia.map(name, url) {
        SocialMediaBubbles(
          name: kWeb,
          url: socialMedia[kWeb],
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10.0)
        }
      ],
    )
  : SizedBox(height: 0.0),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, String> socialMedia = {
    'kWeb': 'http://candice-music.com',
    'kYouTube': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WW7K3WWin_8',
    'kInstagram': 'https://www.instagram.com/candicemusicoff/',
    'kSpotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1rHf7vRCsDRBkbA1XGT9e1'
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: _buildRow(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildRow() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    socialMedia.forEach((k, v) {
      //Add a SocialMediaBubbles
      widgets.add(
        SocialMediaBubbles(
          name: k,
          url: v,
        ),
      );
      //Add a SizedBox
      widgets.add(SizedBox(width: 12.0));
    });

    return widgets;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! Please consider also upvoting the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You can remove the `forEach` by using a for loop within a list iterable. E.g. `final widgets = [for (var entry in socialMedia.entries) SocialMediaBubbles(...)];`